# Parse date: get month in text using Locale

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to parse a string like ***18/10/2018 08:00*** into ***18 october, 08:00***

I should be able to get the month in the selected language of my app.

Right now I am getting the month number and I don't want to create a function to parse it from *Int* to *String*; there has to be an easier method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat to achieve this...

Example...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
String formatedDate = DateFormat.format("dd MMMM, HH:mm", sdf.parse(dateTime)).toString();
```

Comment: @NilOleart As you know this is java code and we can use java and kotlin together as kotlin documentation says it is interperotable. But i will suggest you to convert this code to kotlin or follow the aminography answer.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà I know. I've translated it. Actually, AndroidStudio can convert java to kotlin when you paste the code. Thank you anyway :D

Comment: Okay thats great then. IDE rocks.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
val input = "18/10/2018 08:00"
val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
val date = inputFormat.parse(input)
val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, HH:mm")
val output = outputFormat.format(date)
System.out.println(output)
```